# Value not passing to view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to display a value in angularJS and cannot figure out why it won't print.

I have defined the variable as `$scope.totalBTC`, and calling it with `{{totalBTC}}`. Seems straight forward but I cannot make it work.

app.js

```js
app.controller('exchangeValuesController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.totalBTC = 0;
  $scope.exchangeValues = [];

  var request = $http.get('/exchange-values');

  request.success(function(exchangeValues) {

    $scope.exchangeValues = exchangeValues;
    $scope.totalBTC = exchangeValues.totalBTC;
    console.log('totalBTC: ' + exchangeValues.totalBTC) // totalBTC: 9.45
  });

  request.error(function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  });
});
```

```html
index.ejs

<h1>Poloniex Balances</h1>
<div ng-controller="exchangeValuesController">
  <p>
    <!-- totalBTC will not print on the ejs page -->
    <h1>Total BTC Value: {{totalBTC}}</h1>
  </p>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>rate</th>
      <th>Total BTC Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="currency in exchangeValues">
      <!-- these values are correctly printing  -->
      <td>{{currency.currency}}</td>
      <td>{{currency.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{currency.rate}}</td>
      <td>{{currency.totalBTC}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How I can make {{totalBTC}} display correctly?

Comment: Looks like **exchangeValues** is an array. Can you print that?

Comment: As `console.log('totalBTC: ' + exchangeValues.totalBTC)` return `totalBTC: 9.45`. `{{totalBTC}}` should also work fine.

Comment: Yeah it turned out it was actually started coming through as undefined at some point without me realizing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like server returns as an array, so try using

```
$scope.totalBTC = exchangeValues[0].totalBTC;
```